# How will I be able to remove [NSNull Null] objects from NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, nsmutablearray

I need to remove Null object added by

```
 [mutArrSkills addObject:[NSNull null]];
```

Do I need to iterate? Is there any function to remove all null values from NSMutableArray?

If need to Iterate, how will I do that?

Comment: the removeObjectIdenticalTo also gonna itrate the array so why don't you itrate your self.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [NSMutableArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003688)'s `removeObjectIdenticalTo:` method, as follows

```
[mutArrSkills removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNull null]];
```

to remove the null values. No need to iterate.

Comment: Aure you sure? I'm not because `Objects are considered identical if their object addresses are the same.`. AS you should know, `[NSNull null] != [NSNull null]`...

Comment: Yes, as far as concerned in this case, the elements that are added by ` [mutArrSkills addObject:[NSNull null]];` are removed with that call.

Comment: AS you should know, [NSNull null] is indeed equal to [NSNull null]. There is only one instance ever of class NSNull. All objects of that class are the same pointer.

Answer (score 1):

[`removeObjectIdenticalTo:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABDDBAG)

> Removes all occurrences of a given object in the array.
>
> **Discussion**
> This method uses the indexOfObjectIdenticalTo: method to locate matches and then removes them by using removeObjectAtIndex:. Thus, matches are determined using object addresses. If the array does not contain anObject, the method has no effect (although it does incur the overhead of searching the contents).

Comment: Aure you sure? I'm not because `Objects are considered identical if their object addresses are the same.`. AS you should know, `[NSNull null] != [NSNull null]`...

Comment: @Nekto pls refer my answer down.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this,

```
NSNull *nullValue = [NSNull null]; 

[mutArrSkills removeObjectIdenticalTo:nullValue];
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you first have to cast your `Swift` `Array` to `NSArray`, make and make it mutable so you can remove the `Objective-C` leftover elements, then cast it back to `Array`.

```
Fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type

// my crashing array, containing a not String element, like NSNull or anything else
let myUnsafeSwiftArray: [String]

// make it safely NSArray, then make it mutable
let mutableUnsafeArray = NSMutableArray(array: myUnsafeSwiftArray as NSArray)

// remove leftover class, like [NSNull null] aka NSNull.init()
unsafeTextures.removeObject(identicalTo: NSNull.init())

// Cast the safe array back to its supposed to by element type
let safeArray = unsafeTextures as? [String]
```

Answer (score -1):

You may iterate like this.

```
for(int i=0,i<[mutArrSkills count]; i++)
{
  if([[mutArrSkills objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[NSNull Class]])
    {
    [mutArrSkills removeObjectAtIndex:i];  
   }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work at all if you have two successive NSNull objects in the array.