# NSMutableArray removing Nulls

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsnull

From my JSON feed i create a `NSMutableArray` to hold my `NDDictionary` objects. When I come to display this in a `UITableView` it crashes due to `<null>` Values. So I need to know, How exactly can i remove these `"<null>"` Objects from my Array.

Here is a print out of what is returned from the JSON:

```
Service Names: (
"Nether Edge to Woodhouse",
"Barnsley to Rotherham",
"Woodhouse to Nether Edge",
"Rotherham to Barnsley",
"Doncaster to Worksop",
"Worksop to Doncaster",
"Penistone to Barnsley Interchange",
"Barnsley Interchange to Penistone",
"<null>",
"Barnsley to Rotherham",
"Rotherham to Barnsley",
"<null>",
"Buttershaw to St Bedes RC Upper School",
"St Bedes RC Upper School to Buttershaw",
"<null>",
"Sandholme Drive to Ilkley GS",
"Ilkley GS to Sandholme Drive",
"<null>",
"Barnsley to Rotherham",
"Rotherham to Barnsley"
)
```

I have tried things such as :

```
[serviceNames removeObject:@"<null>"];
[serviceNames removeObject:[NSNull null]];
```

and

```
[serviceNames removeObjectsIdenticalTo:@"<null>"];
[serviceNames removeObjectsIdenticalTo:[NSNull Null]];
```

All which have failed up to now so can anybody please tell me a simple way of removing the `"<null>"`objects from this array as its driving me mad!

Comment: Loop over the array, log each item and its class name.

Comment: Check for Null when you create cell for your table.

Comment: Try [arr removeObject:@"\"<null>\""];

Comment: `serviceNames` isn't really an `NSMutableArray`; from your own logs I can see this is the case `-[__NSArrayI removeObjectIdenticalTo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8bb4370`. that is why `[serviceNames removeObjectsIdenticalTo:[NSNull Null]];` isn't working.

Comment: Someone already suggested using a predicate so I will just leave this here and upvote their answer. NSArray *nonNullResults = [serviceNames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != null"]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,
Note: this I not tested.

> tempArray is your real array.

```
NSMutableArray *mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i = 0; i < [tempArray count]; i++) {
    id obj = [tempArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if (![obj  isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) { // or if (![obj  isKindOfClass:[[NSNull null]class]]) {
        [mainArray addObject:obj];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@",mainArray);
```

Comment: Get the following Stack when I use this: http://pastie.org/private/zdy6kqmtaknexghqj5pvqw

Comment: Check my updated answer. And let me know it works for you or not?

Answer (score 1):

you may use a NSPredicate :

```
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (SELF CONTAINS %@)", @"<null>"];
    [serviceNames filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

With a for-in loop over the serviceNames, you should notice all the null strings are gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all Null from array in this way

```
for(uint i=0;i<serviceNames.count;i++)
{
    if([[serviceNames objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        [serviceNames removeObjectAtIndex:i];
}
```

then reload your table

Answer (score 0):

here is a shorter and possibly more efficient way to do it:

**Edit: the answer to this [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192301/how-will-i-be-able-to-remove-nsnull-null-objects-from-nsmutablearray?rq=1) is even better than my own.**

simply use `[mutArrSkills removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNull null]];`

if your array is not an `NSMutableArray` then get a mutable copy like so `NSMutableArray* mutableArray = [array mutableCopy];` This is why when you tried this solution it didn't work; because you are trying to mutate an *immutable* array.

`[NSNull null]` produces a singleton object so you can just compare equality of address if you like. It an unnecessary check and slow down to either use `isKindOfClass:` or `isEqual:`. If you are going to iterate the objects yourself just use the `==` operator instead of sending costly messages.

Comment: When using the removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNull null]]; i get the following: http://pastie.org/private/oudhurkymn6vszdmmfalcq Thanks

Comment: @DamienD that is because you are sending that message to an _immutable_ array. you need a mutable array (I updated my answer to show you).

Comment: I am calling it on a NSMutableArray :/                     tempServiceNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: @DamienD show me your code, because you wouldn't be getting that error if you were really sending that message to a mutable array. you are doing something wrong.

Comment: header file is at the top, and the implementation is below, http://pastie.org/private/fk2gw29skho8wshi5ss0a Thanks.

Comment: @DamienD you are clobbering your mutable array on line 126 `tempServiceNames = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"desc"];` that is assigning a new immutable array to `tempServiceNames`. If you want mutable containters returned by `NSJSONSerialization` then you must pass `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` as an option. I question your design here; your initialization of all your temporary objects is meaningless and they probably don't belong in your interface :/

Comment: Tempoary objects where created for one of the above answers to test. I originally only used one set of arrays for each. I shall attept to add the option and see if this resolves the issue.

Comment: @DamienD even then you still have a bunch of useless `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` lines. there is no point in allocating a new array only to overwrite it later.

Comment: Okay, so how would you recommend doing this? I apologise for my mistakes, I am still quite new to C#.

Comment: @DamienD you need more reputation before we can chat :( this isn't C# BTW... [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better forum for getting advice on improving code.

Comment: :/ thats a shame, could do with some support from somebody who knows about this as im Java self taught. Is there no way outside of here we can chat or is that against T&C's.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a category on NSNull that responded to the most common messages sent to other JSON objects (integerValue, etc). It returned whatever was most appropriate for the message. Worked like a charm.