# Remove null objects from mutable array in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a mutable array of checked box

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfCheckedBox = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:namePropertyString, lastNamePropertyString, companyPropertyString, workEmailPropertyString, personalEmailPropertyString, workPhonePropertyString, cellNumberPropertyString, nil];
    [arrayOfCheckedBox removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNull null]]; //not working
    NSLog(@"array of check box = %@", arrayOfCheckedBox);
```

If I click on check boxes at index 0, 1 and 4, it will only collect object at indexes 0 and 1 only and will not detect index 4 at all.

I get the values at the selected index in log before getting it in arrayOfCheckedBox. How to get checked values in this case?

Comment: try replacing `[NSNull null]` to nil, have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192301/how-will-i-be-able-to-remove-nsnull-null-objects-from-nsmutablearray)

Comment: i tried nil before [nsnull null]. didn't wokr

Comment: @OptimusPrime :see my Answer,it may be solve you prob.

Comment: a `NSIndexSet` could be more useful for your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're hitting a `nil` value, so the `arrayWithObjects:` method thinks you're at the end of the list of objects.

Something like this will work:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfCheckedBox = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:7];

if (namePropertyString)
    [arrayOfCheckedBox addObject:namePropertyString];

if (lastNamePropertyString)
    [arrayOfCheckedBox addObject:lastNamePropertyString];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing the check box values in an array of BOOLs.
Wrap them in NSNumbers first and unwrap them to retrieve them.

Wrap to store,

```
[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]
```

Unwrap to retrieve,

```
[[your_array objectAtIndex:index] boolValue]
```

Comment: You can wrap them in an NSNumber, `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]`, then unwrap them with `[[your_array objectAtIndex:index] boolValue];`

Answer (score -1):

For null values appear to be string literals @"" rather than the NSNull.So use following way to remove null object :

```
    NSLog(@"%d", [arrayOfCheckedBox count]);
    NSString *nullString = @"<null>";
    [arrayOfCheckedBox removeObject:nullString];
    NSLog(@"%d", [arrayOfCheckedBox count]);
```

Comment: "<null>" only appears in some printing or formatting paths. It's not equivalent to nil or [NSNull null] in any other context.