# iOS : application crashing for null values while displaying scrolling tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, null

I am receiving `JSON` response from server, most of the values are `NULL`, I have written these lines of code, assuming that it should work fine, but somehow it is giving me again the same `Null` error, Kindly review my question and help me out..

```
 NSMutableArray * s = [data valueForKey:@"my_images"];
         NSLog(@"array is  %@",s);



         for (int i=0; i < [s count]; i++)
         {

             if (s[i] !=[NSNull null])
             {
                 NSLog(@"%@",s[i]);

             }

             else
             {

                 NSLog(@"%@",s[i]);

             }

         }
```

I need to get split images on that location instead of merged values, My output is here..

```
 array is  (
"mobile2.jpg,mobile1.jpg,mobile.jpg",
"artificial.jpg,grass.jpg",
"11.JPG,chair.JPG",
"oc.jpg",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>"
```

)

Comment: Your `if` / `else` statements give the same output, don't they? Also, if you're checking for `null` but the fields are `"<null>"` then they aren't `null`, they're strings. Sorry if I'm not understanding your question. As for splitting the first three strings, you can use `componentsSeparatedByString` and check for commas.

Comment: you are searching value for key `my_images`. What you have given as output is not valid JSON. It is just an array of strings. Can you post your JSON to the question.

Comment: yes it is.. it goes to to the end of mutable array, but at the end it is crashing

Comment: Please paste the full output. We need to see the value you get from `[data valueForKey:@"my_images"];` or the full json output.

Comment: see updated.. full values

Comment: I've already voted this as 'Unclear what you're asking', because this seems like it's probably an XY problem, because there's no clear error statement--no actual error message, no explanation of what you're ***actually*** trying to do... and the provided answers are only explaining how to remove `[NSNull null]` from a mutable array.  If that's the actual question, this question is a duplicate [of this existing question which already has plenty of answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9192301/2792531).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the value of object is not null before add it to the array.

```
NSArray* s = [data valueForKey:@"my_images"];
NSMutableArray* data = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id object in s) {
   if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] == NO) {
       [data addObject:object];
   }
}
```

Comment: There's a much easier way, given we can just pull the objects from the dictionary as a mutable array: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9192301/2792531

Answer (score 0):

Check NUll Data.. Hope this is HelpFull.

```
 if ([str isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
    return str;
}
else
{
    str = [str isEqual:[NSNull null]]?@"":[str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    if ([str isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || [str isEqual:[NSNull null]] || [str isEqualToString:@"<null>"]  || [str isEqualToString:@"(null)"] || [str isEqualToString:@""] || [str isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        return @"";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

u can try this

```
for (NSString *item in images){
    if (item && ![item isEqual:[NSNull null]]){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: It'd be impossible for `item` to be `nil` in a for-in loop.  You can't put `nil` in an array, and `nil` serves as the terminator for the loop, so even if you could manage `nil` in any of the indexes, it'd simply serve as a signal that the loop made it to the end and wouldn't enter the body with that argument.